# rebajar vs. bajar

Tags: uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

I'm accustomed to using "rebajar" to indicate weight loss. However, when I type the following into Google Translate, I'm asked if I mean "bajado":

> He rebajado casi 60 libras

Are both acceptable?

I learned Spanish from living in Puerto Rico for many years, so maybe it's a regional difference?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a regional difference, yes. In fact *bajar (de peso)* is much more common. Google Search assumes you've made a mistake if you search for "rebajar de peso", and Google Ngram (which indexes books) shows "bajar de peso" is the norm (see below for graphs).

The main meaning of *rebajar* according to the DLE is transitive:

> tr. Reducir la altura, el volumen o la intensidad a algo.

The expression *«he rebajado casi 60 libras»* is therefore (according to the DLE) grammatically incorrect, since the verb is supposed to be transitive but there's no direct object there (*casi 60 libras* is a complement, not an object).

Now, *bajar* has among its meanings

> intr. Disminuir o llegar a un nivel o una medida más bajos.

In this usage, *«he bajado casi 60 libras»* is an intransitive phrase with a complement. The complement (*casi 60 libras*) is a bit particular because it's not introduced by a preposition, but it can be parsed more or less like English "I'm down almost 60 pounds".

Is it acceptable to use *rebajar* as people do in Puerto Rico? Well, if they do it consistently, then it's part of the Spanish language and it's acceptable. It will be understood by any Spanish speaker, even if it sounds a bit off. The DLE doesn't always include all regional usage variants.

[image: rebajar de peso]

[image: bajar vs. rebajar]

Answer (score 1):

I did the following google search:

> me puse en dieta y rebajé

(without quotation marks), and I found that plenty of people seem to express themselves this way, for example:

> Rebajé 12 libras mi primer mes https://www.nootric.es/pregunta-nutricion/ayuda-788
>
> Perdí 20 libras y rebajé dos tallas de ropa https://www.tualdia.com/recetas-de-dietas/dietas-para-adelgazar/dieta-del-arroz-pollo-y-manzana.html

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/rebajar) documents this meaning of *rebajar*:

> **1 c** (en cantidad)
>
> [nivel, temperatura] to reduce * lower
>
> [luz, tensión, intensidad] to reduce
>
> **[peso] to lose**
>
> [dolor] to ease * alleviate
>
> *la OMS aconseja rebajar el consumo de azúcar en la dieta the WHO recommends reducing or lowering the sugar intake in one’s diet*
>
> ***quiere rebajar cinco kilos he wants to take off or lose five kilos***
>
> *el hotel rebajó su categoría de cinco a cuatro estrellas the hotel reduced its rating from five-star to four-star*